# Facebook wall post in Arabic issue

Tags: facebook, arabic, facebook-wall

When I am trying to add static Arabic text to facebook publish box through javascript, its showing question marks or boxes. English is appearing perfectly. Using Google API isn't the solution as it is producing messed up translation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an encoding issue. Which encoding are you using? You should almost always use UTF-8.